# Display WordPress on example.com/blog/ and m.example.com/blog/

Tags: wordpress, dns

I'm looking to display the same WordPress blog on a mobile subdomain and the main domain in a subfolder. This would look like the following:

- example.com/blog/ (with main theme and customisations)
- m.example.com/blog/ (with mobile theme and customisations)

However, is this possible or do I need to install a separate blog and duplicate content onto the mobile blog from the main blog?

PS - This is a test environment at this stage, and I will handle user-agent switching and [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) duplicate content considerations.

Answer (score 0):

*This is doable but you there's no simple unobtrusive solution.*

**There is ONE simple way to do this.** Hack the core, find `wp_set_wpdb_vars()` in `wp-includes/load.php` and right after `$prefix = $wpdb->set_prefix( $table_prefix );` add this:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'm.domain.tld'){
    $wpdb->options = "mobile_{$wpdb->options}";
    $wpdb->postmeta = "mobile_{$wpdb->postmeta}";
    $wpdb->commentmeta = "mobile_{$wpdb->commentmeta}";
}else{
    $wpdb->options = "mobiless_{$wpdb->options}";
    $wpdb->postmeta = "mobiless_{$wpdb->postmeta}";
    $wpdb->commentmeta = "mobiless_{$wpdb->commentmeta}";
}
```

This trick will sandbox `options and metas` into two different sets of tables. This way they will not overwrite but if you use different settings for plugins installed. You can just sandbox the `options table` if you have control over plugins and prevent settings collision.

In your `wp-config.php` you will need to do this:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'm.domain.tld'){
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-config-mobile.php');
}else{
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-config-mobiless.php');
}
```

Both must have same settings *(dbname, prefix)* except `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME`. You can use one file if you don't hard define `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in the [`wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php).

Comment: Thanks 5ubliminal, really appreciate your help. I'll try that today.